# Proof of a root of a function given that the integral over the domain is equal to 0

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f : [a,b] \to R$ be Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$, $a < b$. Let $f(x) \ge 0$, $\forall x \in [a,b]$, and let the integral of $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b = 0$. Let $f$ be continuous at the point $p \in (a,b)$.
>
> Prove that $f(p) = 0$.

I've been given a hint:

> Suppose $f(p) = \alpha > 0$. Show that there exist real numbers $c$ and $d$ such that $a<c<p<d<b$ and $f(x)> \alpha$, $\forall x\in(c,d)$. Hence $f ≥ \alphaχ$ where $χ$ is the characteristic function of the interval $(c, d)$.

I can't quite figure how to show that such a $c$ and $d$ exists (I can get a vague outline in my head, maybe due to the integral $= 0$) and then saying that the integral would be greater than $\frac\alpha2\cdot(d-c)$. I just need some help getting started with this proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(p) > 0$, then since $f$ is continuous at $p$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x\in [a,b]$, $|x - p| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(p)| < f(p)/2$. Hence, if $c = p - \delta/2$ and $d = p + \delta/2$, then $f(x) > f(p)/2$ for all $x\in [c,d]$. Since $f \ge 0$ on $[a,b]$,

$$\int_a^b f(x)\, dx = \int_a^c f(x)\, dx + \int_c^d f(x)\, dx + \int_d^b f(x)\, dx \ge \int_c^d f(x)\, dx \ge \frac{f(p)}{2}(d - c) > 0,$$

a contradiction.